# Зачем явно приводить результат вызова malloc() к char*?

Tags: c, malloc, преобразование-типов

В некоторых отрывках кода наблюдаю приведение `malloc()` к `(char *)`, `(int *)` и т.п. Зачем это делается?

Например:

```
char *p;
p = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Я так делаю по привычке :) На самом деле не нужно. Но когда перед глазами строк "сто тыщ" кода, это может быть важно, чтобы глаз цеплялся.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Во времена динозавров в языке С не было типа `void *`. Идея универсального указателя `void *` пришла в С намного позже (причем не откуда-нибудь, а из С++). А до того времени в качестве "универсального" указательного типа использовался именно `char *`. Функция `malloc` возвращала результат именно типа `char *`. Именно в те времена и существовала необходимость для выполнения неявного приведения результата `malloc` от `char *` к конкретному типу указателя-получателя. В примерах кода, написанных на достандартном С, включая первые версии K&R, это приведение везде присутствует именно по этой причине.

С появлением в языке типа `void *`, неявно приводящегося к любому указательному типу, и с последующим переходом `malloc` на `void *`, необходимость в явном приведении отпала. Однако в большом количестве старого кода его еще можно увидеть. Это приведение перекочевало и во второе издание K&R С, написанное еще до появления первого стандарта С. Несмотря на то, что второе издание задним числом привели в соответствие со стандартом С89/90, примеры кода в нем никто исправлять не стал. В результате студенты, использующие книгу K&R для обучения, "нахватываются" этот странной привычки оттуда, слепо следуя ей как "карго культу".

В современном С-коде выполнять такое приведение имеет смысл разве что только в кросс-компилируемом С-С++ коде, т.к. в С++ указатель `void *` к другим типам сам по себе не приводится. В частности, например, при реализации кросс-компилируемых макросов и inline-функций в заголовочных файлах.

(Наследием тех времен, когда в качестве универсального указателя в С использовался тип `char *` в современной спецификации языка является гарантия того, что объектное представление и требования выравнивания типов `void *` и `char *` обязаны совпадать.)

---

Справедливости ради надо заметить, что один аргумент современных любителей явно приводить результат `malloc` в С коде (не предназначенном для кросс-компиляции) таки содержит определенное рациональное зерно. В коде вроде

```
T* p;
...
p = (T *) malloc(N * sizeof(T));
```

если кто-то поменяет тип указателя в объявлении `p` с `T *` на `U *`, но при этом забудет исправить выделение памяти через `malloc`, то в вызове `malloc` компилятором будет сгенерировано диагностическое сообщение о несоответствии типов указателей. Да, это действительно так.

Однако более грамотным вариантом защиты от подобных проблем будет использование идиомы с "типонезависимым" выделением памяти

```
p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);
```

которое само по себе "автоматически" подстроится под вышеупомянутое изменение типа.

Answer (score 4):

Функция `malloc` выделяет блок памяти размера, который передали в параметрах и возвращает указатель на первый байт выделенного блока. Тип возвращаемого значения  `(void*)` - указатель на какие-то данные, нетипизированный указатель

Выделенный блок памяти присваивается указателю, который имеет точный тип. Поэтому мы должны явно преобразовать `(void*)` к типу указателя, к которому присваиваем данный блок.

**Важно отметить, 

Если вы компилируете программу С++ компилятором, тогда явное преобразование нужно делать. 

Если вы компилируете программу С компилятором, тогда явное преобразование можно опустить.**

Comment: Почему "мы должны явно преобразовать", если он прекрасно преобразуется *неявно*?

Comment: если вы будете компилировать программу С++ компилятором, то он будет требовать явное преобразование.

Comment: С чего бы это вдруг я стану компилировать С программу С++ компилятором? С и С++ - очень разные языки.

Comment: Вы не будете. И никто бы лучше не делал. Но редко бывают сценарии, что в С++ проект попадает код сторонней библиотеки, которая написана на С.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что люди пишут С код в расчете на то, что кто-то в будущем будет делать тупой copy-paste этого кода внутрь С++ кода? Это смешно. Смешанных С и С++ проектов - огромное количество, но для этого нет никакой необходимости явно превращать С код в С++ код. С и С++ прекрасно сосуществуют в разных единицах трансляции одного проекта .

Comment: @Ant, нет, я это не сказал, в том то и дело, что этого и не делается. В этом и нет нужды. В этом и кроется возможный нюанс, который и был отмечен в ответе, который может возникнуть в результате временного, бестолкового, как угодно можно это охарактеризовать, копипаста.

Answer (score 2):

Соглашаясь с предыдущими ораторами, я выскажу свою крамольную мысль - потому что многие ухитряются считать С чем-то вроде кастрированного С++, и компилировать программы на С в режиме С++. А он требует приведения...

Так что все эти приведения - просто затычка, чтоб компилятор не ругался, перешедшая в привычку :)

Да оно и не так уж плохо - по крайней мере видно, для чего именно `malloc` память выделял.